# Failed Binder Transaction Facebook API Login Failure

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to run the "Scrumptious" sample android application included in the Facebook SDK. However, when I hit the login button and enter my credentials, I get this error message in the log saying

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Has anyone had issues with this? Would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896892/facebook-sdk-3-0-android

Comment: @E.Odebugg thanks, yeah i checked that, but the link posted in the solution was broken...

Comment: this might be a wild guess, but do you have a stable internet connection?

Comment: @E.Odebugg lol yeah i do why? does the link work for you? this is the one i was referring to: http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/

Comment: I ment for the app. To make sure it is not a network issue

Comment: I have this issue now. How did you resolve it? It is not a hashkey error. I tried that snippet of code Facebook provides and I got the same Hashkey value that I had before. It seems like its a bundle error. Too much data might be getting passed through the intent. And also, this error only appears with a Test Developer testing my app. Not with me.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and it turned out I had the wrong key hash registered with my app. I used the snippet of code posted in  [Facebook sdk 3.0 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896892/facebook-sdk-3-0-android) to determine my key hash and the problem went away.

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.scrumptious", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and solved it by going to res/values/strings.xml of the sample project and saving my Facebook app ID in the app_id field.

Comment: This is the perfect solution! I tried so many other approaches and only this one worked !!!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I saved the app ID but I still get an error